# How to define a TSP without returning to depot?

Tags: python-3.x, or-tools

A routing model is initialized with a depot parameter

```
pywrapcp.RoutingModel(tsp_size, num_routes, depot, model_params)
```

But what if I don't care about which node is the depot? And how can I allow the start and end nodes to be different?

Answer (score 1):

there are some hints for

1. fixing start and end nodes
2. arbitrary start and end nodes

in the section [common tasks](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/routing_tasks#arbitrary_start) of the or guide.
(1) is solved by using the `RoutingModel` constructor that takes parameters start and end while (2) is solved by introducing an additional variable which can be reached for free from any other point and which is set as the depot using the `RoutingModel` constructor that takes the depot parameter.

To fix only one of the nodes (and leave the other arbitrary), use a dummy variable as depot and modify the cost matrix so that going out from depot can only be `start` or going back to depot can only be `end`. Do so by making other transits more expensive than the most expensive possible tour.